# Create a sequence of random numbers with labels

Tags: r, matrix, label, assign

I want to generate random probability numbers which each of them has a label. For example, by generating 3 numbers, we have three labels:

```
n <- 3
prob <- runif(n,0,1)
[1] 0.3199110 0.2809717 0.6234215

lab <- LETTERS[1:n]
[1] "A" "B" "C"

assignnn <- data.frame(lab , prob)
lab      prob
1   A 0.3199110
2   B 0.2809717
3   C 0.6234215
```

If i sample from these three numbers and use them in a matrix:

```
sam <- sample(prob , 6 , replace = TRUE)
[1] 0.2809717 0.3199110 0.2809717 0.3199110 0.2809717 0.6234215

mat <- matrix(sam,2,3)
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.2809717 0.2809717 0.2809717
[2,] 0.3199110 0.3199110 0.6234215
```

I want to get the label matrix as below:

```
       [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,]    B         B          B
[2,]    A         A          C
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```r
# Set n = 3
n <- 3

# Take a random sample from a uniform distribution
prob <- runif(n, 0, 1)

# Assign names to the elements of 'prob'
names(prob) <- LETTERS[1:n]

# View prob
prob
#>         A         B         C 
#> 0.1631039 0.6475393 0.5345181

# Take a random sample of n = 6 from 'prob' (with replacement)
sam <- sample(prob, 6, replace = TRUE)

# View 'sam'
sam
#>         A         C         A         B         A         A 
#> 0.1631039 0.5345181 0.1631039 0.6475393 0.1631039 0.1631039

# Create a matrix
matrix(sam, 2, 3)
#>           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] 0.1631039 0.1631039 0.1631039
#> [2,] 0.5345181 0.6475393 0.1631039

# Matrix using the element names
matrix(names(sam), 2, 3)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,] "A"  "A"  "A" 
#> [2,] "C"  "B"  "A"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can use `match` :

```
mat[] <- assignnn$lab[match(mat, assignnn$prob)]
mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "C"  "A"  "A" 
#[2,] "C"  "B"  "C"
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1235)
n <- 3
prob <- runif(n,0,1)
lab <- LETTERS[1:n]
assignnn <- data.frame(lab , prob)
assignnn
#  lab       prob
#1   A 0.24259237
#2   B 0.51535594
#3   C 0.09942167
sam <- sample(prob , 6 , replace = TRUE)
mat <- matrix(sam,2,3)
mat
#           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
#[1,] 0.09942167 0.2425924 0.24259237
#[2,] 0.09942167 0.5153559 0.09942167
```